# Is it possible to embed Android.VideoView in Xamarin Forms ContentView

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, android-videoview

I need to create a mobile app that have to run on android 7.0 - 9.0 and the latest iOS

So in my VS 2017 15.9.6 on Windows 10 I try to use Xamarin.Forms 3.4 in a shared project as a container for a native Android.VideoView.

I try to figure out how to do that, since the Mono.Android examples don't use Xamarin.Forms. So, do I need a kind of #ifdef in the xaml file, to embedd ths Android VideoView? Or am I completely wrong with that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Shared Projects, you can define the native views in XAML and then access them in the code behind (which is basically a requirement since native Android|iOS controls are not directly bindable and most have method calls for setting up features that would not available via XAML (i.e. a VideoView has a `.SetVideoURI` method that has no Xamarin-based wrapper property so you have to execute that method to play a video).

#### XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
    xmlns:androidGraphics="clr-namespace:Android.Graphics;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
    xmlns:androidContext="clr-namespace:Forms40Shared.Droid;assembly=Forms40Shared.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
    x:Class="Forms40Shared.NativeEmbedPage" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="20">
            <androidWidget:TextView x:Arguments="{x:Static androidContext:MainActivity.Instance}" Text="Welcome to Forms!" TextSize="24" View.HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                <androidWidget:TextView.Typeface>
                    <androidGraphics:Typeface x:FactoryMethod="Create">
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:String>cursive</x:String>
                            <androidGraphics:TypefaceStyle>Normal</androidGraphics:TypefaceStyle>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </androidGraphics:Typeface>
                </androidWidget:TextView.Typeface>
            </androidWidget:TextView>
            <ContentView x:Name="contentView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="200" >
                <androidWidget:VideoView x:Arguments="{x:Static androidContext:MainActivity.Instance}"  />
            </ContentView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note**: **Do not enable** `XamlCompilation` at the global assembly level or on XAML pages that contain native views as it will not work (and there are not errors during compiling or runtime, the views just do not show up as they have been stripped out)...

#### MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label ~~~~
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        Instance = this;

        ~~~
    }
```

#### Code Behind:

```
#if __ANDROID__
            var videoView = (contentView as NativeViewWrapper).NativeView as VideoView;
            videoView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"android.resource://{Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName}/raw/fireplace"));
            videoView.Start();
#elif __IOS__
            ~~~
#endif
```

#### [image]Output:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790186.aspx

Comment: That sounds really great! Allthough it seems I have missed something: In your code behind snippet, you convert the _content_ object to _Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.NativeViewWrapper_.
Since there is no such "content" object in the xaml file, but a "contentView" named Item, I have adjusted the snippet to

var videoView = (contentView as NativeViewWrapper).NativeView as VideoView;
Alas, contentView as NativeViewWrapper evaluates to **null**

Can you please help, what's wrong with my code? Thanxs.

Comment: Additionally, I have disabled XamlCompilation in _App.xaml_ and adjusted the namespace from _Forms40Shared_ to my project's namespace. This only thing missing is: where do I get a static instance of my _MainActivity_?? Please help..

Comment: that was it - thanksalot. Do you by chance know, how to set the _HorizontalOptions_ and _VerticalOptions_ of the ContentView, so that the video uses the max size without loosing its aspect ratio?

Comment: @xy You would either need to know beforehand the aspect ratio and set the contentview to that size (via embedding it in a grid/absolute/etc.. layout, or calculate it at runtime from the actual video. Personally I would use and AbsoluteLayout and set the ContentView via proportional constraints (of course this means that I know the video's aspect ratio, 4:3, 19:6, etc..0