# Share the app feature implement using dependency service in xamarin forms android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am implementing Share the App feature in Xamarin forms project. Yes, there are libraries which are available, But library conflicts with a version of Xamarin forms package and I have already completed all the stuff and don't want any issue, and I want to implement using dependency service by doing platform specific coding in Android and iOS without any package.

Here, I am using intent for share the app from Android project by making custom renderer. But I am getting error.

```
public class ShareTheAppRenderer : IShareTheApp
{
    public void ShareApp()
    {
        var mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
        sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Check out our app at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=");
        sendIntent.SetType("text/plain");
        mainActivity.StartActivity(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

[image: Please see attached screenshot.]

Please give some suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can use the "CurrentActivityPlugin" (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) to obtain the context of the `MainActvity` instance that is hosting your Xamarin.Forms app.

Comment: Please don't add code and errors as images, but rather as text. Amongst others, code and errors in an image renders the question unusable for people that are visually impaired and have to rely on screen readers. Plus, this renders the question less searchable.

Comment: Okay, Paul Kertscher, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply. But I got the solution for this. Here I don't want to use any other libraries to achieve this.

My Working solution is as below:

```
public class ShareTheAppRenderer : IShareTheApp
{
    public void ShareApp()
    {
        var appPackageName = Forms.Context.PackageName;
        var myIntent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
        myIntent.SetType("text/plain");
        myIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Check out our app at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(myIntent, "Choose an App"));
    }
}
```

This solution works for me.

Comment: FYI: `Forms.Context` is obsolete

Comment: Yes, I know it is obsolate, but I have to implement without any third party packages, So if you have any solution which I can achieve this task with the help of dependency service, please provide me. Thank you.

Comment: You can just create a static variable in your MainActivity class, see the "MainActivity" section of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470572/is-it-possible-to-embed-android-videoview-in-xamarin-forms-contentview/54472484#54472484

Comment: Okay. Thank you.